# class android support v4 print helper has been already added to output

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I just updated my android studio to the latest version with the new gradle version also, running my application gives me an error class android support v4 has been already added to the output don't know what is going wrong i check if there is a jar duplicated or a library duplicated couldn't find anything. here is my app:build.gradle

```
enter code here

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '21.1.1'
lintOptions
        {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            //abortOnError true
        }
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "package name"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes
        {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
            }
        }
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
    incremental true
}

 }

 dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 compile project('Libraries:UniversalImageLoader')
 compile project('Libraries:facebook')
 compile project('Libraries:pull-to-refresh')
 compile files('Libraries/gcm.jar')
 compile files('Libraries/quickblox-android-sdk-chat-2.0.jar')
 compile files('Libraries/quickblox-android-sdk-core-2.0.jar')
 compile files('Libraries/quickblox-android-sdk-messages-2.0.jar')
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
 compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3'
 compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
 compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2"
 }
```

I took of this
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2'
i thought its already included in the appcompat-v7 but it did not solve my issue yet

Comment: If you run the Gradle `dependencies` task on your app module, you might be able to pinpoint where it's being duplicated. I usually do that from the command line. From the **app module's directory** I run `../gradlew dependencies`.

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded my Android Studio version to 0.8.6 and the "Duplicate Copies" error disappear.

It isn't a perfect solution but for now and for me it is the unique solution currently.